# how to publish my docker image

Tags: docker

question:

1. I'ved pull iamge from ubuntu:14.04 and do something (install jdk / tomcat / vim and so on)
2. i have a account dormi330 in https://registry.hub.docker.com/

   wzq@wzq-pc:~$docker images

   REPOSITORY   TAG         IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE

   tmv2         latest      e30b070f3b34        15 hours ago        1.32 GB

this image works well.
i want to push the image tmv2 to my repository,so i can pull this image in other pc
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/dormi330/ubuntu_tmv_v1_war/tags/manage/
currently it's a empty repo

but when i push

```
wzq@wzq-pc:~$ docker push dormi330/tmv2
The push refers to a repository [dormi330/tmv2] (len: 0)
2014/09/24 10:28:05 No such id: dormi330/tmv2 // <<===note here No such id
```

it seems like i do sth wrong,
what's the right way to push image to my web repository?
thx!

Answer (score 6):

This is incorrect
`docker build dormi330/tmv2 .`

Use like this
`docker build -t dormi330/tmv2 .`

Answer (score 0):

solved

my image name should be same with my repo name,
that is

i should tag the image with the name dormi330/ubuntu_tmv_v1_war
then push it